Struggling with memory issues in aggregating large e-commerce data for analytical platform in Elasticsearch
We are building an analytical platform which can see the sales related data for an e-commerce platform. How we implemented is that, we denormalized the data from our PostgreSQL DB and inserted into ElasticSearch using Logstash.
To give a basic idea, We have only one index, and contains 3 type of data within a single index.

sales - which contains sales related info and a product ID for which sales have happened.
pageview - which contains how much page views have been there for each products for each single day
products - basic information about products and its pricing, color etc.

In DEV environment, we only had a very small data size:

sales - 4k records
pageview - 200k
products - 100k

Our spec at that time was 16GB ram for our instance, with 2 nodes and 5 shards.
In our application we need to show sales and pageview that happened for each product for each day. So on API calls, we aggregate the data using aggregate queries using the terms "product_id" for sales and pageview data type.
The problem was, we will be able to show only the "product" which had any sales or page view. Now, the client wants to see the products which don't have any sales or page view.
So, we added two fields into the product data type - sales = 0 and pageview = 0 and aggregated the data like, aggregate of pageview + products = result contains products without any views as well now.
We did the same for the sales data queries.
When we released this to staging, we realized that data we are dealing with is very huge volume.

pageview = 318million (and growing)
sales = 30 million
products = 3.3 million

Now, if we do the same "aggregate" queries, we will be getting heapOutOfMemory and we are having upper limit of 65K records per aggregation buckets.
So, we increased our spec to 64GB ram/ 8 core CPU, which is way too expensive, we are still facing the same heapOutOfMemeory issues. We are late for production release due to this unforeseen behaviour, we don't know what to do. Any suggestion?
